# Use PS to copy last week's log files?

Tags: powershell

I've been tasked with changing our current powershell script from gathering the last month of IIS logs from our servers to getting the logs each week.  I don't see any syntax for week.

Here's the current script for the last month of logs -

```
Clear
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Copying started at: " (get-date)
$aDate=$(get-date).AddMonths(-1) 
$aDateSet=@($aDate)
$firstDay = Get-Date $aDate -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0
$lastDay = (($firstDay).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1))
Write-Host " "
get-childitem "path" | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -ge $firstDay  -and $_.lastwritetime -le $lastDay }  | copy-item -destination "path"
```

So how would I change this to grab the last week's logs? or is that possible with this script?

Comment: `I don't see any syntax for week.` A week is 7 days. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can select file system items for last week:

1. Get `[DateTime]` representing beginning of last week:

   ```
   $beginningOfLastWeek = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-(Get-Date).DayOfWeek-1-6)
   ```
2. Get `[DateTime]` representing beginning of this week:

   ```
   $beginningOfThisWeek = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-(Get-Date).DayOfWeek)
   ```
3. Get files within those two times:

   ```
   Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -ge $beginningOfLastWeek) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $beginningOfThisWeek) } ...
   ```